# Use array result as multiplier for the original data frame

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, dataframe, r-factor

for a given data frame I would like to multiply values of an array to a column of the data frame. The data frame consists of rows, containing a name, a numerical value and two factor values:

```
name credit gender group
n1 10 m A
n2 20 f B
n3 30 m A
n4 40 m B
n5 50 f C
```

This data frame can be generated using the commands:

```
name    <- c('n1','n2','n3','n4','n5')
credit  <- c(10,20,30,40,50)
gender  <- c('m','f','m','m','f')
group   <- c('A','B','A','B','C')
DF      <-data.frame(cbind(name,credit,gender,group))
# binds columns together and uses it as a data frame
```

Additionally we have a matrix derived from the data frame (in more complex cases this will be an array). This matrix contains the sum value of all contracts that fall into a particular category (characterized by m/f and A/B/C):

```
   m f
A 40 NA
B 40 20
C NA 50
```

The goal is to multiply the values in DF$credit by using the corresponding value assigned to each category in the matrix, e.g. the value 10 of the first row in DF would be multiplied by 40 (the category defined by m and A).

The result would look like:

```
name credit gender group result
n1 10 m A 400
n2 20 f B 400
n3 30 m A 1200
n4 40 m B 1600
n5 50 f C 2500
```

If possible, I would like to perform this using the R base package but I am open for any helpful solutions that work nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a set of indices into `derived` (being your derived matrix) by making an index matrix out of `DF$group` and `DF$gender`. The reason the `as.character` is there is because `DF$group` and `DF$gender` are factors, whereas I just want character indices.

```
>idx = matrix( c(as.character(DF$group),as.character(DF$gender)),ncol=2)
>idx
[,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "m" 
[2,] "B"  "f" 
[3,] "A"  "m" 
[4,] "B"  "m" 
[5,] "C"  "f" 
>DF$result = DF$credit * derived[idx]
```

Note with that last line, using the code you have above to generate `DF`, your numeric columns turn out as factors (ie `DF$credit` is a factor). In that case you need to do `as.numeric(DF$credit)*derived[idx]`. However, I imagine that in your actual data your data frame doesn't have `DF$credit` as a factor but instead as a numeric.

Comment: +1 for matrix lookup. But ... If he used `cbind` before he used data.frame, then everything was "character" and `data.frame` in its default settings turned it all into factor. So needs to have the `as.numeric(as.character(...))` treatment to get correct results.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I'm aware that as.numeric(...) has to be applied to DF$credit. For the example your answer works very nicely. I will try to test if for more complicated cases in which the derived object is an array.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the data.frame object, don't use cbind, it's not necessary and it forces the credit variable to become a factor.

Just use `DF <- data.frame(name, credit, gender, group)`

Then run a for loop that goes through each row in your data.frame object.

```
n <- length(DF$credit)
result <- rep(0, n)
for(i in 1:n) {
  result[i] <- DF$credit[i] * sum(DF$credit[DF$gender==DF$gender[i] & DF$group==DF$group[i]])
}
```

Replace your data.frame object with this new one that includes your results.

```
DF <- data.frame(name, credit, gender, group, result)
```

Comment: It's not `cbind` that coerces to a factor. It coerces to "character" mode. It's the `data.frame` function that has a default of `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` that would coerce all of the character vectors to factors.

Comment: This is a third method that also produces the correct result on the example data. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the [`plyr`](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) package, but you can do this using the base `by` function:

```
> by(DF, DF['name'], function (row) row$credit * m[as.character(row$group), as.character(row$gender)])
name: n1
[1] 400
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
name: n2
[1] 400
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
name: n3
[1] 1200
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
name: n4
[1] 1600
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
name: n5
[1] 2500
```

`plyr` can give you the result as a data frame which is nice:

```
> ddply(DF, .(name), function (row) row$credit * m[as.character(row$group), as.character(row$gender)])
  name   V1
1   n1  400
2   n2  400
3   n3 1200
4   n4 1600
5   n5 2500
```

Comment: +1 `plyr`, I'd have recommended it but for OP preferring base R. `ddply` is awesome!

Comment: Dear Daniel, thanks for your example. I tried the by function which produces a list. With the assumption that 'm' stands for the derived matrix I could get it to work (a little description on what your code is doing would have made it a bit easier to understand). When I have more time I will look into the plyr package as well.